# Using ObjectId inside Mongoc.jl pipeline

Tags: mongodb, julia

I am trying to use ObjectId inside mongoc.jl aggregation pipeline like this:

```
pipeline = Mongoc.BSON("""
  [
    {
      "\$match": {
        "_id": {"\$ne": Mongoc.BSONObjectId(X)}
      }
    }
  ]
""")
```

It not working!

Comment: Hey, can you please provide more details as to what is not working and such. This will help us help you!

Comment: I found the solution: {"\$oid": "X"}

Comment: Please update your Q  and add an answer to help the next Person who may run into this.